# interface for Visual Studio Errors (want to replace compiler)

Tags: visual-studio, clang

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use a new compiler within visual studio, and how the interface between compiler and IDE works to make error messages and source code locations "work" (eg double click goes to location).

Context: trying to integrate clang

Comment: The VS version matters a great deal, the C++ build tool chain was completely rewritten in VS2010.  There's a lot you can do with msbuild, little before VS2010 but makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a [Visal Studio Integration SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx) which presumably is used by Intel. The Intel compilers can add themselves to the VS IDE and replace the Microsoft compilers.

Answer (score 2):

I am using NMake for "integrating" clang with Visual Studio. You get the convenience of syntax highlighting and intellisense with the power of LLVM. You have to manually make an nmake buildscript file though (which is quite cumbersome).

There is a clang switch called -fdiagnostics-format=msvc that will output the error and warnings in a format that Visual Studio understands (so you can quickly jump to errors or warnings in your code).